# How SIGINT gets passed to grandchild (and how to do this programmatically)

Tags: python, linux, bash, signals

using linux/bash/python3, I create a grandchild process `sleep 123`. When I call `p.terminate()`, this kills the child process (init takes over the grandchild `sleep 123`). However, from the python interpreter I can still press Ctrl+C to kill the grandchild.

My questions are 1) how it's possible for the python interpreter to send a SIGINT to the grand-child when it's now parented by init, and 2) how I kill the grandchild programmatically. I've tried `p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)`, playing with `stdin=PIPE` etc, but can't get it to work.

```
gnr@localhost: python3
Python 3.3.1
>>> from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
>>> p = Popen(['bash', '-c', '(sleep 123)'])

gnr@localhost: ps -AF | grep sleep
gnr 5081 5078 0 26526 1168 6 14:03 pts/26 00:00:00 bash -c (sleep 123)
gnr 5082 5081 0 25228 564  4 14:03 pts/26 00:00:00 sleep 123

>>> p.terminate()

gnr@localhost: ps -AF | grep sleep
gnr 5082    1 0 25228 564  4 14:03 pts/26 00:00:00 sleep 123   #init inherits

>>>        # hits Ctrl+C
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>

gnr@localhost: ps -AF | grep sleep
#grandchild is dead
```

UPDATE: I ended up using pexpect (which takes care of a lot of the pty and termios stuff for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grandchild is still having the terminal as its standard input, regardless of any reparenting, so pressing Ctrl-C in the terminal sends it a SIGINT. To do it yourself, you need to know the PID of the grandchild. There isn't an easy way to obtain it; your child process may have spawned a dozen children of its own, they may have spawned more children, etc. It is not clear at all which one would be "the" grandchild

You however can send a signal to all processes in the foreground group.

```
os.kill(-os.getpgid(os.getpid()),signal.SIGINT)
```

This will only work if Python itself is attached to the terminal of course.

Comment: If I set `stdin=PIPE` when I create my child process, I see the same behavior, so I don't see how the terminal has any connection to the grandchild's stdin at that point.

Comment: You are right, this is not stdin but [a different mechanism](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Terminal.html).

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful in pointing me to the fact that I can use a controlling terminal to kill grandchild processes.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux sending the kill or terminate signals to a process does not end its child processes. They become orphaned and adopted by the init system process.

You could use the [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) package. You can do something like this with it:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import psutil

proc = Popen(['bash', '-c', '(sleep 123)'])
parent = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
for child in parent.children(recursive=True):
    child.terminate()

parent.terminate()
```